# NSTableView Delegate Called But Data not showing

Tags: xcode4.2, nstableview, cocoa-bindings, nstableviewcell

i have a very strange problem with NSTableView in XCode 4.2.
I've set the datasource an delegate for the table. My table has 3 columns where each of the column has an identifier ("name","mugshot","lastSeen").
My delegate

```
-(id)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
```

is being called, but there is still the default value "TableViewCell" shown in the table cells. the method is implemented as follows:

```
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
    NSMutableDictionary *villain = [self.villains objectAtIndex:row];
    id keyName = [tableColumn identifier];
    id objectValue = [villain objectForKey:keyName];
    return objectValue;
}
```

The tableColumnIdentifier is correct.
I have no idea why the text is not showing.

br,
martin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in interface builder, make sure the Table Column contains a "Text Field Cell". if not, try dragging out a Text Field Cell on top of whatever cell is there.

this is assuming objectValue is an NSString?

Comment: thanks! there was a static text cell inside. i replaced it with a text field cell and this solved my problem!